# jQuery Get Selector Value Help

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a WP Blog with a few DIVs generated through PHP loops. I would like to be able to show additional about a DIV when someone clicks on it.

The code looks like this:

```
<div class="story item-1">
<div class="story item-2">
<div class="story item-3">
<div class="story item-4">
```

(etc. Could be any number of these.)

Clicking on one of the items above should make one of the following appear:

```
<div class="data preview-1">
<div class="data preview-2">
<div class="data preview-3">
<div class="data preview-4">
```

I'm doing the following:

```
$('.story').click( function() {
  var getNum   =  jQuery(this).attr('class');
  alert('hi ' + getNum);
});
```

But how do extract the "number" value (1,2,3,4,etc.) of the item I just clicked into a variable? If I can get that into a variable such as "num" I can then easily use jQuery .hide and .show to perform actions. What I have so far gets the entire class value. Just need the number from the second class.

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I'd `.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the hyphen, [and `.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) the last item (the number) off the resulting array. Then `.show()` the appropriate preview.

```
$('.story').click( function() {
    var getNum = this.className.split('-').pop();
    $('.data.preview-' + getNum).show();
});
```

Comment: First time asking a question on Stack Overflow, didn't expect such a damn fast response! Thanks Patrick!

Comment: @Sahas - You're welcome. I think you'll find that responses here will typically be very quick, at least in the jQuery camp. :o)

Comment: Woops, found a bug. I'm using another selector named "selected" after the class="item-1" for instance. When I use the code you provided, it worked, but in certain cases the value getNum will include the word "selected" following the number I was looking for. How do I ignore that last item as it will be moving around to indicate a performed action?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out!
    `var getNum = this.className.split('-').pop().split(' '); var getNum = getNum[0];`

Comment: @Sahas - I should have mentioned that it would be fragile to changes in the classes. Looks like you found a good solution. :o)

Answer (score 2):

Of course you *could* use string manipulation to pull out the id, but I propose a better solution:

On `DOMReady`, loop through all the div's, and assign an index to the elements using jQuery's lightweight data storage mechanism, [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

Disclaimer: **untested**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div.story').each(function(index) {
      $.data(this, "num", index);
   });
});
```

Then you can pull it out in your click:

```
$('.story').click( function() {
  var getNum   =  $.data(this, "num");
  alert('hi ' + getNum);
});
```

That's just an example, you may end up needed extra metadata, and you can bind whatever you want to the elements, and use them later.

Comment: Always good to see creative uses of the `index` of `.each()` (as well as the fast access version of `$.data()`). Although, if you're going to take the data storage route, in this case I might be inclined to skip `$.data()` and take advantage of the fact that `.each()` creates a closure. If you just assign the click handlers inside the `.each()`, you can reference the persistent `index` directly. +1 :o)

Comment: Yes, you are right. The perfect example of the love/hate relationship we have with closures. :) Also, i just think `.data` is uber cool. :)

Comment: Ah, see for me it is the opposite. I'm blown away by closures, but go hot/cold on using `.data()`. Funny how that is. :o)

Comment: Well the reason for that is im primarily a server-side developer (so i deal with data, object scoping, etc). So when i see things like closures, i immediately gag. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.story').click(function() {
    var index = /item-(\d)/.exec($(this).attr('class'))[1] - 1;
    $('.data').hide().eq(index).show();
});
```